# What is the upkeep cost of a mount, animal companion, or familiar?

Tags: equipment, familiars, animal-companions, pathfinder-2e, mount

The section on animals in the Equipment chapter (Core 294) gives prices for renting or purchasing an animal. However, we haven't been able to find any rules for cost of animal feed or other upkeep.

How much should I charge my players for the upkeep of a mount, animal companion, or familiar? I could understand that a familiar wouldn't have an upkeep cost since it's magical, but it seems to me that there would be expenses for mounts and animal companions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Additional creatures have the same upkeep as any player character

Companions, hirelings, familiars, and any other creatures traveling with the party should be accounted for when expending resources such as [Rations](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=40) and [water](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=62). Paizo did not include any specific rules regarding larger creatures eating more, so it is up to the GM to determine if 1 week of rations is enough to feed your Large Boar for a week or only 3 days (as an example).

Most other maintenance is handwaved as part of the rules for [Cost of Living](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=545) and [Subsisting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=27). Other potential costs, such as stabling, are outlined in [Services](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?Category=2).

---

The bottom line is that, for an adventurer, the costs of maintaining allies should be minimal. Beyond the first level or two, unless your group has fun with micromanagement, it is unlikely to be relevant (except *maybe* for a long stretch of Downtime).

Comment: Great answer and excellent conclusion. And I think expending regular Rations to feed allies – animal or otherwise – is straightforward and simple.

Comment: I might narrate that the players make sure to buy appropriate food for their animals, but charge them the same rate (or double for Large creatures would be my table ruling)